# IN and WHERE, passing in a variable as a string or an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that has a where condition, sometimes the condition can be a string and sometimes it can be an array. If it is an array I need to use IN.

The condition is passed in as a var.

What would be the best solution:

1. Check if the passed in var is an array - if not then put it in an array. Then always run an IN search.
2. Change the SQL that is ran, so if its an array, run an IN search, if not doing a WHERE.

Comment: `In` is in the `Where` clause, they are not exclusive. Think you mean `=` vs `IN`. Version 1. seems easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var = array('test');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` " ? is_array($var) ? "IN (" . implode(',',$var) . ")" : " = " . $var;
```

or just do:

```
$var = array('test');
if(!is_array($var)){
    $var = array($var);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (" . implode(',',$var) . ")";
```

whichever you prefer. In terms of performance, I'd go with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion... I think the best solution and clear to understand is the number 1: check if is an array and if it isn't convert it. Then implode in an ´IN´ clausule. The second one will generate more code.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it to array. Mysql rewrites your query itself without IN if it is necessary.